# How to find length of JSON file in javascript using jsonfile npm

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file that I am using javascript to read, I am able to print it out in console, but I have to manually code the number of objects in the JSON file, the file is really simple with only 3 objects, I would like to create a function that checks how many objects are in JSON file.

Json Code

```
{
    "items": [
    {
        "fname": "Kali",
        "lname": "Flower",
        "age": "19"},
    {
        "fname": "JD",
        "lname": "Wyatt",
        "age": "19"
    }]
}
```

I'm trying to write a javascript function showing how many objects are in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse` to convert the content to object then use `.length` to get the size:

```
JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file)).items.length
```

Explained:

```
const fs = require("fs"); // require fs
const content = fs.readFileSync(file); // read the file content as string
const obj = JSON.parse(content); // convert string to object
const length = obj.items.length;
```

Comment: so if my json file obj name is obj, it would be that instead of str_file right?

Comment: I assume you are using something like this to get the content of the file?
`str_file = fs.readFileSync("test.json"); console.log(str_file)?` ignore `Sync`